# WD EX4100 RAID Adding Drives (4TB Red)

Tags: nas, raid-1

I have an WD EX4100 with two bays open; set to raid1 4x2 x raid1=4tb I want to add 2 more 4tb drives will raid rebuild or do I have to start over?

Comment: Too vague.  What is it you are attempting to get at the end?  Raid 5 = (3) 4T + (1) 4T EC = 12T, Raid 0+1 = (2) 4T striped = 8T and Mirror that.  Raid 1+0 = (2) 4T mirrored = 4T and stripe = 8T...  I don't THINK you can do two separate raid 1's from this single box.

Comment: Currently 2x 4TB RUNNING RAID1 or 4TB usable; want to add 2x 4TB drives for total 16TB non RAID or 8TB RAID 1. By adding the two new drives will the system recognize them and make one RAID1 drive or will I have to rebuild RAID and start over. The point is I need more space but I don't want to loose the data

Comment: I would tend to guess that powering off and removing drive 2 then powering on and going into the settings you could set from raid 1 to jbod.  All your data would exist on the single drive.  Then you could just power off and insert the rest of the disks.  I'm not sure if you could get 16T in jbod mode - may get (4) 4T drives.  You'd have to check the manual for that.  I'm just not that familiar with their OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'd not recommend you to keep the RAID 1 array with the WD My Cloud EX4100, since you'd be adding 2 more HDDs, @Wayne. With the NAS having 4 x 4 TB HDDs you can configure the storage with RAID 5 or RAID 10 even. These configurations would give you a much better performance and better storage capacity.

However, I'd not advise you to do a JBOD because you'd have no amalgamation, pooling or storage structure, which puts the data stored on the My Cloud at risk.

**The backup procedure is a MUST when tempering with any storage, so there's no escaping this one!** What you can do is backup your data from the RAID 1 array somewhere else and change the RAID mode from the Dashboard on your WD My Cloud EX4100. When you click on Storage, you'd be able to see the RAID profile. Once you have all 4 HDDs inside the NAS, you'd be given the option to change the RAID mode to 5 or 10.

The RAID 5 mode provides data redundancy, high read rates, and good performance in most environments. It also provides redundancy with the lowest loss of capacity. RAID 5 is best suited for scenarios where a lot of small input/output (I/O). With 4 x 4 TB, your RAID 5 array would have a total space of 12 TB available (and 4 TB for protection).

The RAID 10 mode combines RAID 0 and RAID 1, so it basically breaks up data into smaller blocks and mirrors the blocks to each RAID 1 drive group. The first RAID 1 drive in each group then duplicates its data to the second drive. RAID 10 is best used with data storage that needs 100% redundancy of mirrored drive groups and that needs the enhanced I/O performance of RAID 0. However, with the 4 x 4 TB HDDs, you'd have only 8 TB available (and the other 8 TB for protection).

You can refer to our [WD Learning Center](http://setup.wd2go.com/?mod=faqs&device=mcp4&faq=raid) for more details on the RAID mode how-to and, of course, the [WD My Cloud EX4100 User Manual.](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/UM/ENG/4779-705140.pdf)

Hope I was helpful. Let me know if you have more questions! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I think I'm going to go with the raid 1.0 it seems to be the best based on the scenarios that you explained once again I appreciate it

Comment: @WayneHughes did you get any way for it ?